# Laravel - Using Union with WhereExists on existing builder object?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, union

I have a query `$trips` which is a simple `where()` query on my trips table:

`$trips = $trips->where("agency_id", $myAgencyId);`

I want to use multiple `whereExists()` queries on this `$trips` Builder object, but Laravel is returning a 500 (with no message). Is my syntax wrong? I worry it's something with the parentheses.

Here's my full query:

```
$trips = $trips->whereExists(function ($query) use ($value) {
                    $query->fromRaw("jsonb_array_elements(pax->'adults'->'persons') as p(person)")
                        ->whereRaw("upper(p.person->>'name') LIKE ?", [$value]);
                })
                ->union(
                    $trips->whereExists(function ($query) use ($value) {
                        $query->fromRaw(
                            "jsonb_array_elements(pax->'infants'->'persons') as i(person)"
                        )
                            ->whereRaw("upper(i.person->>'name') LIKE ?", [$value]);
                    })
                )
                ->union(
                    $trips->whereExists(function ($query) use ($value) {
                        $query->fromRaw(
                            "jsonb_array_elements(pax->'children'->'persons') as c(person)"
                        )
                            ->whereRaw("upper(c.person->>'name') LIKE ?", [$value]);
                    })
                );
```

**NOTE: My query works fine if I subsitute `$trips` directly for the model `Trip`, e.g**:

```
->union(Trip::whereExists(function ($query) use ($value) { [...]
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

I was going the wrong way about the logic. Using `union()` was a bad idea as the `$trips` variable is being reduced in each query. I should instead use `orWhereExists()`.

This solved my problem.